# --AWS ElasticBeanstalk container_commands: Commands trigger errors even if they were correct

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a django project that I want to deploy with ElasticBeanstalk,
I defined a [xxxx.config] file in .ebextensions, the content of the file is:

xxxx.config

```
container_commands:
  acvenv:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate"
  migrate:
    command: "python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate"
```

But the project doesn't deploy unless I remove xxxx.config.

I follow the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

### What am I doing wrong?

The output of eb logs:

2024/03/10 06:43:07.470696 [INFO] Error occurred during build: Command migrate failed

2024/03/10 06:43:07.470721 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.

Comment: How do you know they work correctly? Did you check any EB logs to verify that there are not errors?